# Receiving print error while using ReportLab to print PDFs in Python

Tags: python, pdf-generation, pywin32, reportlab

This is a difficult issue to diagnose, because I am unsure how to even get the full details.  I've been testing for hours and there is no clear pattern.  Every few times I run my script, I receive this printer error (image below):

[image: printer error]

The PDFs go to the printer que, but when there is an error they get stuck there.  I am able to fix by simply unplugging and plugging back in, but I'd really love to put this bug out.

Sometimes it happens after 10 successful prints, other times it has happened every other.

Does anyone see a bug in my code that might be causing this? Or an overall issue with my script as to why this happens occasionally?

```
import os
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
import win32print
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import landscape, portrait
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

# Set up Google Sheets API credentials
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('creds.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Set up printer name and font
printer_name = "Rollo Printer"
font_path = "arial.ttf"

# Register Arial font
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arial', font_path))

# Open the Google Sheet and select Label and Claims worksheets
sheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eRO-30eIZamB5sjBp-Mz2QMKCfGxV037MQO8nS7G7AI/edit#gid=1988901382"
label_sheet = client.open_by_url(sheet_url).worksheet("Label")
claims_sheet = client.open_by_url(sheet_url).worksheet("Claims")

# Get the number of label copies to print
num_copies = int(label_sheet.acell("F2").value)

# Set up label filename and PDF canvas
label_file = "label.pdf"
label_canvas = canvas.Canvas(label_file, pagesize=landscape((400, 250)),bottomup=432)

# Write label text to PDF canvas
label_text = label_sheet.get_all_values()
x_pos = 10  # set initial x position
y_pos = 260  # set initial y position
line_height = 20  # set line height for text
label_canvas.setFont('Arial', 20)
for row in label_text:
    for col in row:
        textobject = label_canvas.beginText()
        textobject.setFont('Arial', 20)
        textobject.setTextOrigin(x_pos, y_pos)
        lines = col.split("\n")
        for line in lines:
            textobject.textLine(line)
            y_pos -= line_height
        label_canvas.drawText(textobject)
        x_pos += 145
        y_pos = 260
    x_pos = 10

# Save the label PDF and print to the printer
label_canvas.save()
for i in range(num_copies):
    os.startfile(label_file, 'printto', printer_name, "", 1)

# Set up claims filename and PDF canvas
claims_file = "claims.pdf"
claims_canvas = canvas.Canvas(claims_file, pagesize=landscape((400, 250)),bottomup=432)

# Write claims text to PDF canvas
claims_text = claims_sheet.get_all_values()
x_pos = 10
y_pos = 260  # set initial y position
line_height = 20
claims_canvas.setFont('Arial', 20)
for row in claims_text:
    for col in row:
        textobject = claims_canvas.beginText()
        textobject.setFont('Arial', 20)
        textobject.setTextOrigin(x_pos, y_pos)
        lines = col.split("\n")
        for line in lines:
            textobject.textLine(line)
            y_pos -= line_height
        claims_canvas.drawText(textobject)
        x_pos += 145
        y_pos = 260
    x_pos = 10

# Save the claims PDF and print to the printer
claims_canvas.save()
os.startfile(claims_file, 'printto', printer_name, "", 1)
```

Comment: Perhaps the file hasn't fully saved when you go to print it?  Try adding a small delay after the `.save()` call.

Comment: great suggestion - will give it a shot, very much makes sense

Comment: @JohnGordon this doesnt seem to fix the issue unfortunately, could you provide guidance as to where exactly to place? I have right above my save lines and am sleeping for 2 seconds

Comment: Put it _below_ the save call, not above.  The goal is to call `save()`, then wait a few seconds to make sure the file is fully saved, before trying to print.  Adding a delay _before_ the save call doesn't really do anything.

Comment: amazing!! thank you so much - working better!!